# installing Lion onto iMac 4,1 fitted with core 2 duo chip

Tags: osx-lion

in order to upgrade XCode to cover ios 5.0.2Im trying to upgrade my iMac 4,1 Snow Leopard to OS Lion - I initially got the message about my processor being of the wrong type so I had it upgraded to a core 2 duo. This now reflected in 'About this Mac' when returning to App Store to purchase Lion I now just get a message saying it cant be done - has anybody with same processor upgrade managed to overcome this problem yet ??

Comment: You can't do a third-party CPU upgrade and expect that OS X will automatically support it.  You need a supported 64-bit-capable system for Lion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question not related to StackOverflow.
Try at Apple's forum, they could have been through the same issue, or try with Google, or check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42241/there-was-an-error-in-the-mac-app-store-please-try-again-later-13) if the error message is #13